# Attaching an audio player to a button

Tags: javascript, html, css, toggle, html5-audio

Here is a working toggle audio player.

You click on it and it goes on and off.

https://jsfiddle.net/sw0ot32z/

[image]

I would like to have that audio player work with this toggle button.

How would I get it to working using mostly the **same javascript setup as the 1st player?**

I want to keep most of the javascript from the 1st code.
The 1st code is a toggle player, I would like to use that audio javascript for the toggle button.

```
<audio></audio>

<div class="       " data-audio="          ">
```

Can the switchButton code be put inside the **1st code**? Can that be done?

https://jsfiddle.net/vsb9u40g/

[image]

How would I do that?

Is this something that is simple to do?

That is what I am trying to do.

I wasn't able to figure it out.

How is this able to be done?

Placing the css and html of **code 2** into the **1st code** I get this error.

**I got this far:** https://jsfiddle.net/jb0nxcef/5/

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";

  const onOffButton = document.querySelector(".switch");

  function switchButton() {
    onOffButton.classList.toggle("on");
  }
  onOffButton.addEventListener("click", switchButton);
})();
```

```css
.switch {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: black;
  width: 150px;
  height: 195px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 0 1px 2px black,
    inset 0 2px 2px -2px white, inset 0 0 2px 15px #47434c,
    inset 0 0 2px 22px black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  perspective: 700px;
}


.switch.on .button {
  transform: translateZ(20px) rotateX(25deg);
  box-shadow: 0 -10px 20px #ff1818;
}


.switch.on .button .light {
  animation: flicker 0.2s infinite 0.3s;
}


.switch.on .button .shine {
  opacity: 1;
}

.switch.on .button .shadow {
  opacity: 0;
}

.switch .button {
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 1, 1);
  transform-origin: center center -20px;
  transform: translateZ(20px) rotateX(-25deg);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  background-color: #9b0621;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: linear-gradient(
    #980000 0%,
    #6f0000 30%,
    #6f0000 70%,
    #980000 100%
  );
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.switch .button::before {
  content: "";
  background: linear-gradient(
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) 10%,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) 30%,
        #650000 75%,
        #320000
      )
      50% 50%/97% 97%,
    #b10000;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  transform-origin: top;
  transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.switch .button::after {
  content: "";
  background-image: linear-gradient(#650000, #320000);
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  transform-origin: top;
  transform: translateY(50px) rotateX(-90deg);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 50px 8px 0px black, 0 80px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.switch .light {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: light-off 1s;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: radial-gradient(#ffc97e, #ff1818 40%, transparent 70%);
}

.switch .dots {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: radial-gradient(transparent 30%, rgba(101, 0, 0, 0.7) 70%);
  background-size: 10px 10px;
}

.switch .characters {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(white, white) 50% 20%/5% 20%,
    radial-gradient(
        circle,
        transparent 50%,
        white 52%,
        white 70%,
        transparent 72%
      )
      50% 80%/33% 25%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.switch .shine {
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 1, 1);
  opacity: 0.3;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(white, transparent 3%) 50% 50%/97% 97%,
    linear-gradient(
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5),
        transparent 50%,
        transparent 80%,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)
      )
      50% 50%/97% 97%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.switch .shadow {
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 1, 1);
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(transparent 70%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8));
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

@keyframes flicker {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  80% {
    opacity: 0.8;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes light-off {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  80% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="switch">
  <div class="button">
    <div class="light"></div>
    <div class="dots"></div>
    <div class="characters"></div>
    <div class="shine"></div>
    <div class="shadow"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't have any source to play. I edited your jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7aw8vg4j/7/

```
<div class="switch">
<audio src="https://getradio.me/svoefm"></audio>
  <div class="button">
    <div class="light"></div>
    <div class="dots"></div>
    <div class="characters"></div>
    <div class="shine"></div>
    <div class="shadow"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and

```
 (function() {
  "use strict";

  const onOffButton = document.querySelector(".switch");

  function switchButton() {
    let audio = document.querySelector('audio');
 
    onOffButton.classList.toggle("on");
    if (onOffButton.classList.contains('on')) {
        audio.play();
    } else {
        audio.pause();
    }
  }
 
  onOffButton.addEventListener("click", switchButton);
})();
```

Comment: Why can’t I get it working?
https://jsfiddle.net/cbz4ry90/3/

It only goes on, not off.

and the button doesn’t change.